# Are $T1$ spaces precisely the topological spaces where singletons are closed?

Tags: general-topology

A $T1$ space is a topological space where, for any 2 points, each has a neighborhood not containing the other. I wonder if every singleton being closed is an **equivalent** condition, and what the proof for that is. I also wonder if the following condition is equivalent: for any 2 points $x$ and $y$, every neighborhood of $x$ is disjoint from every neighborhood of $y$.

Comment: What about [this?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884458/spaces-where-all-singletons-are-closed?rq=1)

Comment: It has no proof.

Comment: Then [see this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830929/in-t1-space-all-singleton-sets-are-closed?rq=1) one.

Comment: What about the 2nd question?

Comment: For the "I also wonder" part: that condition never holds in any topological space with at least two points, because the whole space $X$ is a neighbourhood of every point.

Comment: This completely answers my questions. Thanks.